# Error redirection fail with bind - dig

Tags: io-redirection, dns, bind, dig, null

I'm trying to test some nameservers against a domain name.
For that, I created a script that reads a list of nameservers and asks for a domain name.

Something basic like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

domain=$1
[ -z $domain ] && read -p "DOMAIN NAME: " domain

namefile="./nameserver"

echo "RESULT -  NAMESERVER              DOMAIN                  IP"

for host in $(cat "$namefile"); do
        IPADD=$(dig +short "$host" "$domain" A 2> /dev/null)

        [[ ! -z $IPADD ]] && result="OK" || result="FAIL"

        echo "$result   - Nameserver: $host     - Domain: $domain       - IP answer: $IPADD"
done
```

The issue I'm having is that, when `Dig` fails, it is not redirecting errors to `null`. Thus, the `$IPADD` variable receives a wrong value.

```
# CORRECT nameserver
# dig +short @8.8.8.8 google.com A 2> /dev/null
142.250.218.206
```

---

```
# WRONG nameserver
# dig +short @8.8.8.80 google.com A 2> /dev/null
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If I test it with a wrong nameserver address, I still get an error message, like shown above.

As I understand, when redirecting to `null`, it should **not** display that error message.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The simple answer here is that dig sends errors out to stdout instead of stderr.

Comment: You could use the [return codes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) instead: `dig +short @8.8.8.80 google.com A &> /dev/null; [ $? -eq 9 ] && echo 'No reply from server'` for example.

Comment: @HackSaw, It seems that way, indeed. Where can I find that information?

Comment: dig is part of the Bind package, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what's the issue now. Actually... Not an issue, a behavior.

If I intentionally input an invalid option, Dig gives me a syntax error.

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 google.com -A
Invalid option: -A
Usage:  dig [@global-server] [domain] [q-type] [q-class] {q-opt}
            {global-d-opt} host [@local-server] {local-d-opt}
            [ host [@local-server] {local-d-opt} [...]]

Use "dig -h" (or "dig -h | more") for complete list of options
```

If I do the same, but redirecting `stderr` to `null`, Dig shows me nothing.

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 google.com -A 2> /dev/null
```

Therefore, it seems Dig is correctly redirecting errors to `null`, not to `stdout`.

Now, if I input an incorrect or unresponsive nameserver, Dig actually tells me that it did not get an answer, `connection timed out; no server could be reached`. Dig does not see that as an error.

Also, it returns code 9, which means "*No reply from server*".
In other words, no DNS service could be reached with the provided nameserver.

As I understand it, "*no server could be reached*" might not be the best response. Maybe changing the term *`server`* to *`service`* would enhance that response a bit.

@schrodingerscatcuriosity comment makes more sense to me now and seems to be a possible way to handle Dig's response in my script.
But, since the actual IP response is required, redirecting all output to null (&> /dev/null) is not desired.

I've add a work around to suppress the timeout output.

```
for host in $(cat "$namefile"); do
    result="OK"
    IPADD=$(dig +timeout=1 +short "$host" "$domain" A 2> /dev/null)
    echo $IPADD | grep -s -q "timed out" && { IPADD="Timeout" ; result="FAIL" ; }

    echo "$result   - Nameserver: $host     - Domain: $domain       - IP answer: $IPADD"
done
```

Comment: I'm no expert in redirection, but here's an idea: `$ dig +short @8.8.8.80 google.com A &> /dev/null > /tmp/foo; cat /tmp/foo`. Then you process whatever message from `/tmp/foo`, either error or not.